# Mysql Select columns without group by

Tags: mysql

**Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `shops` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_code` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `retailer_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `shop_closed_temporarily` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `verification_status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=no-action,1=verified,2=rejected,3=pending',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**Data in the table**

```
id user_id shop_code retailer_name shop_closed_temporarily verification_status
1 3 XYZ0001 abc 0 3
2 3 XYZ0002 abd 0 3
3 3 XYZ0003 abe 1 2
4 3 XYZ0004 abf 0 1
5 3 XYZ0005 abf 0 3
6 3 XYZ0005 abf 0 3
```

**Problem:**

I want to get all the distinct "shop_code" records where verification_status = 3 and shop_closed_temporarily = 0.
The result should be having all the columns.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  shops s
WHERE s.user_id = 3
  AND s.shop_closed_temporarily = 0
  AND s.verification_status = 3
GROUP BY s.shop_code
```

**Want to achieve:**
1,2,5
OR
1,2,6
because row 5 and 6 have similar shop_code.

Comment: Why do you think you need `GROUP BY`?  Why would you choose row 5 `or` 6?  They both meet the criteria.  Which would you include or exclude and why?  Selecting the ID is going to mean you get them both.

Comment: Updated the question with what I want to achieve. If it is possible to get without group by please correct the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an aggregation function  eg min()

```
select min(s.id), s.shop_code 
FROM  shops s
WHERE s.user_id = 3
  AND s.shop_closed_temporarily = 0
  AND s.verification_status = 3
GROUP BY s.shop_code
```

or max()

```
select max(s.id), s.shop_code 
FROM
  shops s
WHERE s.user_id = 3
  AND s.shop_closed_temporarily = 0
  AND s.verification_status = 3
GROUP BY s.shop_code
```

and for all the columns

for obtain all the columns you could join the result for you aggreated  query with the table itself  using the id (my_id) retrived  eg: for max(s.id)

```
select s1.* from shops s1
inner join 
(
    select max(s.id) my_id, s.shop_code 
    FROM
      shops s
    WHERE s.user_id = 3
      AND s.shop_closed_temporarily = 0
      AND s.verification_status = 3
    GROUP BY s.shop_code 
) t on t.my_id = s1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT shop_code  FROM `shops`;
```

which returns

```
 shop_code
 XYZ0001
 XYZ0002
 XYZ0003
 XYZ0004
 XYZ0005
```